# Hikari CP java.lang.IllegalStateException: Timer already cancelled

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, jpa, hikaricp

I am using spring boot, JPA with default connection pool(hikari) and getting following error suddenly after a month of application running. CPU suddenly goes 95% and jdbc connection starts failing.

```
# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = none
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always

#Hibernate creation naming strategy - overriding defaults
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl

# Show all queries
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false
spring.jpa.show-sql=false

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults= false
hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
```

Rest of the configuration is defaul.

Stacktrace

```
org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
…nsServiceImpl.computeJobSpecFromOperationAndHttpMethod(JobSpecificationsServiceImpl.java:41)
…rs.JobsCreationApiController.validateJobSpecifications(JobsCreationApiController.java:92)
…er.controllers.JobsCreationApiController.jobRequestGet(JobsCreationApiController.java:119)
com.adobe.campaign.ssthub.router.controllers.JobsCreationApiController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$6341a7e0.invoke(<generated>)
com.adobe.campaign.ssthub.router.controllers.JobsCreationApiController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$cf56659f.jobRequestGet(<generated>)
…e.asr.filter.AsrRequestResponseFilter.doFilterInternal(AsrRequestResponseFilter.java:91)
…e.asr.filter.logging.AsrLoggingFilter.doFilterInternal(AsrLoggingFilter.java:128)
…m.adobe.asr.filter.AsrRequestIdFilter.doFilterInternal(AsrRequestIdFilter.java:94)
…dobe.asr.exception.AsrExceptionFilter.doFilterInternal(AsrExceptionFilter.java:74)
…b.security.ims.IMSAuthorizationFilter.doFilterInternal(IMSAuthorizationFilter.java:90)
…n.ssthub.config.RequestHeaderValidationFilter.doFilter(RequestHeaderValidationFilter.java:64)
    com.adobe.campaign.ssthub.config.XSSFilter.doFilter(XSSFilter.java:22)
caused by org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
…nsServiceImpl.computeJobSpecFromOperationAndHttpMethod(JobSpecificationsServiceImpl.java:41)
…rs.JobsCreationApiController.validateJobSpecifications(JobsCreationApiController.java:92)
…er.controllers.JobsCreationApiController.jobRequestGet(JobsCreationApiController.java:119)
com.adobe.campaign.ssthub.router.controllers.JobsCreationApiController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$6341a7e0.invoke(<generated>)
com.adobe.campaign.ssthub.router.controllers.JobsCreationApiController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$cf56659f.jobRequestGet(<generated>)
…e.asr.filter.AsrRequestResponseFilter.doFilterInternal(AsrRequestResponseFilter.java:91)
…e.asr.filter.logging.AsrLoggingFilter.doFilterInternal(AsrLoggingFilter.java:128)
…m.adobe.asr.filter.AsrRequestIdFilter.doFilterInternal(AsrRequestIdFilter.java:94)
…dobe.asr.exception.AsrExceptionFilter.doFilterInternal(AsrExceptionFilter.java:74)
…b.security.ims.IMSAuthorizationFilter.doFilterInternal(IMSAuthorizationFilter.java:90)
…n.ssthub.config.RequestHeaderValidationFilter.doFilter(RequestHeaderValidationFilter.java:64)
    com.adobe.campaign.ssthub.config.XSSFilter.doFilter(XSSFilter.java:22)
caused by java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30000ms.
…nsServiceImpl.computeJobSpecFromOperationAndHttpMethod(JobSpecificationsServiceImpl.java:41)
…rs.JobsCreationApiController.validateJobSpecifications(JobsCreationApiController.java:92)
…er.controllers.JobsCreationApiController.jobRequestGet(JobsCreationApiController.java:119)
com.adobe.campaign.ssthub.router.controllers.JobsCreationApiController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$6341a7e0.invoke(<generated>)
com.adobe.campaign.ssthub.router.controllers.JobsCreationApiController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$cf56659f.jobRequestGet(<generated>)
…e.asr.filter.AsrRequestResponseFilter.doFilterInternal(AsrRequestResponseFilter.java:91)
…e.asr.filter.logging.AsrLoggingFilter.doFilterInternal(AsrLoggingFilter.java:128)
…m.adobe.asr.filter.AsrRequestIdFilter.doFilterInternal(AsrRequestIdFilter.java:94)
…dobe.asr.exception.AsrExceptionFilter.doFilterInternal(AsrExceptionFilter.java:74)
…b.security.ims.IMSAuthorizationFilter.doFilterInternal(IMSAuthorizationFilter.java:90)
…n.ssthub.config.RequestHeaderValidationFilter.doFilter(RequestHeaderValidationFilter.java:64)
    com.adobe.campaign.ssthub.config.XSSFilter.doFilter(XSSFilter.java:22)
caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException: Timer already cancelled.
…ce.JobSpecificationsServiceImpl.getJobSpecsFromJobType(JobSpecificationsServiceImpl.java:66)
…controllers.TenantsApiController.generateTenantDetails(TenantsApiController.java:100)
…uter.controllers.TenantsApiController.getTenantDetails(TenantsApiController.java:224)
com.adobe.campaign.ssthub.router.controllers.TenantsApiController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$468cad8e.invoke(<generated>)
com.adobe.campaign.ssthub.router.controllers.TenantsApiController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$bd797369.getTenantDetails(<generated>)
…e.asr.filter.AsrRequestResponseFilter.doFilterInternal(AsrRequestResponseFilter.java:91)
…e.asr.filter.logging.AsrLoggingFilter.doFilterInternal(AsrLoggingFilter.java:128)
…m.adobe.asr.filter.AsrRequestIdFilter.doFilterInternal(AsrRequestIdFilter.java:94)
…dobe.asr.exception.AsrExceptionFilter.doFilterInternal(AsrExceptionFilter.java:74)
…b.security.ims.IMSAuthorizationFilter.doFilterInternal(IMSAuthorizationFilter.java:90)
…n.ssthub.config.RequestHeaderValidationFilter.doFilter(RequestHeaderValidationFilter.java:64)
    com.adobe.campaign.ssthub.config.XSSFilter.doFilter(XSSFilter.java:22)
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you get any solution for this issue?